# Script to generate pages - taxonomies not loaded

Tags: php, register-taxonomy

I've created a basic script in my wordpress root folder as a temporary file to generate a batch of new posts.

I've included the line:

```
require_once("wp-load.php");
```

As I've done in the past.

I'm encountering problems that certain taxonomies are not seemingly available in this PHP script when calling e.g.

```
$productterms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product-type', 'parent' => 0 ) );
```

I get a response of invalid-taxonomy.

The taxonomy name is definitely correct and this call to retrieve the terms works in functions.php.

I suspect I have a load order issue - but can anyone suggest how to work around this? Essentially I just need to have a PHP script that will allow me to loop through an array I've compiled to create pages based on that data - but I need the various taxonomies loaded/available to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just use the taxonomy call within wordpress action callback function.

```
add_action('init', 'my_callback_func');
 function my_callback_func() {

//here you can place your get terms 

}
```

Comment: Add this to my stand-alone script or to functions.php? Thanks for replying.

Comment: Well in that case you can give a try in your custom scripts.

Comment: It does work in functions.php (which worked in that context before) - however nothing happens putting that in my standalone php file

Comment: It did work - I forgot to add the switch_to_blog() call as this is a multi-site. Now works fine. Thanks.